# Иконки в метках

Tags: предложение, метки

Предложение добавить, как на английском Stack Overflow.

[image: Иконка phpstorm]
[image: Иконка google-fit]
[image: Иконка intellj-idea]

Улучшится визуальное восприятие, каких-то минусов в их введении не вижу.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что эти иконки являются формой рекламы: это платная услуга.

Comment: @Marshmallow, тогда варианты: **[1]** Получать доход с иконок и на RU SO, **[2]**  Если владельцы RU SO не собираются так зарабатывать, внедрить иконки бесплатно. Можно только для открытого ПО. Спасибо.

Comment: Точно, а потом давайте сделаем анимированные статусы на полэкрана под каждым постом, как на лирушечке.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не ожидал от ув-мого модератора [аргумента вида 2.3.а.](http://xpomo.com/ruskolan/tolpa/demagog.htm) . Что плохого Вы видите в иконках на EN SO? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных хорошо, объясню подробно в ответе.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что лучше этого не делать. Иконки на основном сайте были введены не для удобства участников, а как способ монетизации сайта. Компания, владеющая продуктом, может оплатить добавление иконки, чтобы повысить заметность метки.

По моим ощущениям эти метки добавляют "информационного шума" на страницу и рассредотачивают внимание. Они очень яркие по сравнению с достаточно спокойным и приятным глазу оформлением сайта. Поэтому взгляд сразу "цепляется" за них. Это хорошо для рекламодателя, но плохо для пользователя сайта.

Если какой-то рекламодатель захочет проплатить спонсированную метку на Ru.SO - прекрасно. Сайт должен себя окупать. Но добавлять иконки на все метки подряд - нет, ни в коем случае. Иначе [cайт будет выглядеть примерно так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps%20or%20google-chrome%20or%20google-app-engine%20or%20google-maps-api-3%20or%20google-chrome-extension%20or%20google-apps-script%20or%20google-analytics%20or%20google-api%20or%20google-spreadsheet%20or%20google-drive-sdk%20or%20google-play%20or%20google-cloud-messaging%20or%20google-visualization%20or%20google-plus%20or%20google-play-services%20or%20google-maps-markers%20or%20google-chrome-devtools%20or%20google-calendar%20or%20google-oauth%20or%20google-bigquery):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне наоборот удобными эти иконки кажутся. Без них все теги как одно большое месиво.